# how use the segue to the nextView data?

Tags: swift3, segue

@IBAction func nextPart(_ sender: UIButton) {

```
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "gotoSegueB", sender: counter )   

     performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueTextviewB", sender: showText)   
}


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any!) {
    if segue.identifier == "gotoSegueB" {        
      if let b = segue.destination as? bView{    
        b.infoFromeViewOne =  sender as! Int!   

             if segue.identifier == "segueTextviewB" {
            if let b = segue.destination as? bView{
                b.textFromeViewOne =  sender as! String!
            }
        }

        }
    }
}
```

I want use the segue, to the next view .
I means:  view A is two data to the view B,  in the view B show two type data. one is a point. like: 75. the two is some words.like: "that's cool. you get taht, good job!"

Answer (score 0):

First of all your question is not well formatted. My answer is based on what ever i was able to understand.

## Perform segue step:

`self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "gotoSegueB", sender: self)`

## prepareForSegue method

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "gotoSegueB" {
        if let vcObj = segue.destination as? DashBoardDetailVC {
            vcObj. infoFromeViewOne = sender as! Int!
            vcObj. textFromeViewOne = sender as! String!
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you. I means:  view A is two data to the view B,  in the view B show two type data. one is a point. like: 75. the two is some words.like: "that's cool. you get taht, good job!"